# String length without len function

Tags: python, string-length

Can anyone tell me how can I get the length of a string without using the `len()` function or any string methods. Please anyone tell me as I'm tapping my head madly for the answer.
Thank you.

Answer (score 22):

```
>>> sum(map(lambda x:1, "hello world"))
11

>>> sum(1 for x in "foobar")
6

>>> from itertools import count
>>> zip(count(1), "baz")[-1][0]
3
```

A "tongue twister"

```
>>> sum(not out not in out for out in "shake it all about")
18
```

some recursive solutions

```
>>> def get_string_length(s):
...     return 1 + get_string_length(s[1:]) if s else 0
... 
>>> get_string_length("hello world")
11
>>> def get_string_length_gen(s):
...     yield 1 + next(get_string_length_gen(s[1:])) if s else 0
... 
>>> next(get_string_length_gen("hello world"))
11
>>>
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's an O(1) method:

```
def strlen(s):
    if s == "": return 0
    return s.rindex(s[-1]) + 1
```

In other words, it doesn't work by counting the characters, so should be just as fast for a 1GB string as it is for a 1 byte string.

It works by looking at the last character and searching from the very end to find that character. Since it's the last character it will always find it at the first place it looks, essentially always returning the index of the last character. The length is just one more than the index of the last character.

Comment: `rindex` is a `str` method --- BBBZZZZZZZTTTTT

Comment: John Machin: What's wrong with `str` methods? The OP only said not to use `string` methods.

Answer (score 5):

Why you need to avoid the len function is beyond me, but strings are iterables.  You should be able to do this:

```
strlen = 0

for c in myString:
  strlen += 1
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get the length of the string with a `for` loop.

For example, instead of:

```
string=input("Enter a string")
print(len(string))
```

Do this:

```
string=input("Enter a string")
a=0
for letter in string:
  a=a+1
print(a)
```

Answer (score 3):

Using while loop

```
a = 'string'
count = 0

while True:
    try:
        if a[count]:
            count += 1
    except IndexError as e:
        break

print(count)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a weird question so here's a weird answer!

```
try:
  for i in itertools.count(): mystring[i]
except IndexError:
  pass
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import re
>>> s
'mylongstring'
>>> re.subn(".","1",s)[-1]
12
>>>
```

If string contains new lines

```
>>> s="mys\ntring\n"
>>> re.compile(".",re.DOTALL).subn("",s)[-1]
10
```

Comment: Doesn't work if string contains a newline! You need the re.DOTANY flag.

Answer (score 2):

Make a file-like object from the string, read the entire object, then tell your offset:

```
>>> import StringIO
>>> ss = StringIO.StringIO("ABCDEFGHIJ")
>>> ss.read()
'ABCDEFGHIJ'
>>> ss.tell()
10
```

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this, its pretty simple and easy

```
def calculate_length(a):
    x=0
    for i in a:
       x+=1
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a method which isn't using neither `len` nor iteration:

```
>>> a = 'a' * 200000
>>> a.rindex(a[-1]) + 1
200000
```

To make it work for lists, which don't have `rindex`, use:

```
>>> a = list(range(200000))
>>> a.index(a[-1], -1) + 1
200000
```

Answer (score 1):

easy:

```
length=0
for x in "This is a string":
    length+=1
print(length)
```

Comment: hey thats too cooll but can u tell me how this is working in a string range bcause we really dont know the range and in a for loop how can this be interprate as a integer

Comment: Python strings are basically a list of characters. So in this code, it's looping through each character in the string and adding 1 to the counter (length in this case). If you want to see how it works, add print(x) right before the length+=1 line.

Answer (score 0):

Not very efficient but very concise:

```
def string_length(s):    
    if s == '': return 0
    return 1 + string_length(s[1:])
```

Comment: Variant of @gnibbler's magnum opus.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it by counting the number of occurences of the empty string within the string:

```
def strlen(s):
    return s.count('') - 1
```

Since `"".count("")` returns 1, you have to subtract 1 to get the string's length.

Comment: `count` is a `str` method --- BBBZZZZZZZTTTTT

Comment: John Machin: Surely every other solution implicitly calls *some* method of `str`. The assignment only says not to use `string` methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
def length(object):#Define the length calculation function

    count = 0  #initializing the length to be equal to zero
    object = input() #enter the argument 

    for i in object:
        count=count+1

    print("Length of the string is"+str(count))

length(object)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't post answers on obviously off topic / bad questions! [See: **Should one advise on off topic questions?**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572/1768232) In addition, when posting answers consisting primarily of a code snippet, please [add some text to explain what the code does](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers).

Answer (score 0):

String length without using len function in python-

```
def strlen(myStr):
    if(myStr==""):
       return 0
    else:
       return 1+strlen(myStr[1:])
```

Answer (score -1):

```
a = 'malayalam'
length = 0
for i in a:
    if i == "":
        break
    else:
        length+=1

print length
```

This code verifies the length of a string by counting until ""(end of the string ).If the string reaches an end, the loop breaks and will return the final length of the string.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: This is basically the same solution as multiuple existing answers, just worse as the `if` is completely unneccessary (and demonstrates that you don't know how iterating over strings works in python). Why exactly would you post a bad answer to a 5 year old question that is already more than exhaustively answered?

Answer (score -3):

Create a for loop

```
styx = "How do I count this without using len function"
number = 0
for c in styx:
   number = 0 + 1
print(number)
```

Comment: how is `number = 0 + 1` going to work? this answer is incorrect and also redundand, see for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3992205/3157428) doing the same as you wanted to show.