# sum up to 4 digits with limitations

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a program that sums up to 4 digits, with some limitaitions such as:

1) The input can be only up to 4 digits.

2) The input can be only a positive number

3) The input can't be float

4) There can't be loop function

5) There can't be len function

After this, which I have succeed coding

I'm trying to make a list of variables that can be between 0 to 9 and than to sum them together.
If someone can help me solve it, it will be great. its only my first week coding and I'm in a bit trouble.

This is my code:

```
num = float(input("Please enter any number up to 4 digits: \n"))


if num < 0:
    print ("Please enter a positive number")
elif num > 9999:
    print ("Please enter up to 4 digits")
elif (num % 1 != 0): 
    print ("Please enter only integer and not float")

num =str(num)
num = list(num)
x = (int(num)[0])
y = (int(num)[1])
z = (int(num)[2])
w = (int(num)[3])


if int(x) > 0 and int(x) <= 9:
    sum = x
elif int(y) >= 0 and int(y) >= 9:
    sum = x+y
elif int(z) >= 0 and int(z) >= 9:
    sum = x+y+z
elif int(w) >= 0 and int(w) >= 9:
    sum = (x+y+z+w)
```

Thanks.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what your question is. What specific issues are you having?

Comment: `sum` is a built-in Python function. You should rename your variable something like `my_sum`.

Comment: sorry, I'll try to be more clear. there can be up to 4 digits, which mean, there can be 2 and 3 digits to sum. I tried to bring up 4 variables: x, y, z, w and they can be integers between 0-9 and than to sum them up

Comment: when I'm trying to run the code on idle and it's fail and show me:  x = (int(num)[0])
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'

Comment: The point is when someone puts negative number or more than 4 digits it will print to the user that he suppose to put positive number or two put up to 4 digits. but this code works fine. I just don't know how to fix the list of the variables in order to sum them up.

Comment: furthermore, I can't use len and loops in this code

Comment: Then that just breaks the solution I built that I'm currently writing as an answer since the closest I could get to keeping your current approach but keeping it functional was a `while True:` loop. I'm not refactoring my code now for a second go - that should be in the question. Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your code, not just the one that you have described:

**Problem 1 - Floats as Strings**

```
num = str(num)
num = list(num)
```

Say you input the number `123`, this as a float is `123.0` so when converted to a string and then list you'd have `num == ['1', '2', '3', '.', '0']`. This is going to cause you problems when you assign `w` as `'.'` is not a valid character that `int` can understand:

```
num = int(num)
num = str(num)
num = list(num)
```

or:

```
num = list(int(str(num)))
```

**Problem 2 - Assigning values**

```
x = (int(num)[0])
y = (int(num)[1])
z = (int(num)[2])
w = (int(num)[3])
```

This won't work, when you want to index a value in a list you should use `num[i]` but you're calling `int` on the whole list `int(num)`.  The extra brackets are also superfluous:

```
x = int(num[0])
y = int(num[1])
z = int(num[2])
w = int(num[3])
```

**Problem 3 - Indexing**

Great, now you can get values into `x`, `y`, `z` and `w`. But only if you input 4 digits, if you input any less like `123`, you'll have `num == [1,2,3]`.  This means that when you call `w = int(num[3])` you'll get an `IndexError` because `num` doesn't have any values at index `3`. At this point you've mentioned that you can't use the `len` function or loops, so instead you can use this code snippet (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3992334/3270037)):

```
length = sum(map(lambda x:1, num))
```

Then use if statements to get the appropriate values (I've also assigned default values of 0 to each variable):

```
x, y, z, w = 0, 0, 0, 0
x = int(num[0])
if length >= 2:
    y = int(num[1])
if length >= 3:
    z = int(num[2])
if length >= 4:
    w = int(num[3])
```

At this point `x`, `y`, `z` and `w` all have values and you can just use:

```
my_sum = x + y + z + w
```

to get your final value:

```
num = float(input("Please enter any number up to 4 digits: \n"))

if num < 0:
    print ("Please enter a positive number")
elif num > 9999:
    print ("Please enter up to 4 digits")
elif (num % 1 != 0): 
    print ("Please enter only integer and not float")

num = list(str(int(num)))
length = sum(map(lambda x:1, num))

x, y, z, w = 0, 0, 0, 0
x = int(num[0])
if length >= 2:
    y = int(num[1])
if length >= 3:
    z = int(num[2])
if length >= 4:
    w = int(num[3])

my_sum = x + y + z + w
```

**Bonus Problem - Input Validation**

This only leaves the problem of having to validate user input which you can do using recursion, this was my final solution that I put together quickly:

```
def get_input(msg):
    try:
        num = float(input(msg))
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a number, not a string")
        return get_input(msg)
    if num < 0:
        print ("Please enter a positive number")
        return get_input(msg)
    elif num > 9999:
        print ("Please enter up to 4 digits")
        return get_input(msg)
    elif (num % 1 != 0): 
        print ("Please enter only integer and not float")
        return get_input(msg)
    else:
        return int(num)

num = get_input("Please enter any number up to 4 digits: \n")
s = sum(map(int,list(str(num))))
print(s)
```